# c struct syntax with assignment?

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to get my head around structs. It seems ok in theory (e.g. a very concise and clear explanation: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs110/hws/structs.html)

But then I find this in a code I'm messing with:

```
static struct pci_driver ik220_driver = {
    name:           DRV_NAME,
    id_table:       ik220_tbl,
    probe:          ik220_init_one,
    remove:         ik220_remove_one,
};
```

What does the `=` operator do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `=` initializes a struct of type `pci_driver`, named `ik220_driver`, with the specified values for fields.

You are just assigning a variable, but it's a compound type.

Comment: It's worth to note however that `field: value,` is not standard C syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Work it up in parts.  `struct pci_driver` is a type. `ik220_driver` is a variable name. `static` sets the variable scope, so the rest: `= {...}` is specifying the value of the variable (which in this case happens to be a struct).